# FileUtils.listFiles and IOFileFilter

Tags: java, apache-commons, fileutils

Hi i want to recursively check if the files and subfolders of a certain directory contain a certain string so tried this

```
package com.tecsys.sm.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter;

import com.tecsys.sm.util.WindowsDirectories;

public class ApacheListOfFiles {
public static void main(String[] args){
    final String envName= "test_trunkcpsm";
    WindowsDirectories wd = new WindowsDirectories();
    File startPath =  new File(wd.getStartMenuDir()+File.separator+"Programs");
    Collection<File> listF = FileUtils.listFiles(startPath, new IOFileFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(file.getName().contains(envName)){
            System.out.println(file);
            return true;
        }else
        return false;
    }
},TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE);
System.out.println(listF.size());
Iterator<File> it = listF.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("Le fichier est : "+it.next());
}
}
}
```

The output of this is the following:

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\TECSYS\iTopia Environments\test_trunkcpsm
>   0

So he finds the file i am searching for but still return an empty list, why is that ? And also while we are at it, when is the first accept called ? i have some difficulties understanding how this class works.

Comment: Debug it !!.. You will find which accept gets called at last.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me, may be the reason is `false` returned in the first `accept()`.

You may also want to look at `DelegateFileFilter` to implement a single `accept()`.

Or to use this single call for the job:

```
Collection listF = FileUtils.listFiles(
    startPath, new WildcardFileFilter("*" + envName + "*"), TrueFileFilter.TRUE);
```